# What is this 50-pin LCD panel interface? How can I connect it to a Raspberry Pi MIPI or to HDMI?

Tags: raspberry-pi, lcd

I would like to buy the [Elegoo LCD display](https://www.elegoo.com/collections/parts-accessories/products/elegoo-5-5-inch-2k-lcd-for-mars) which has the following pinout (sent by the supplier):

[image: pinout]

The item description claims it is MIPI. Is it? I see 4 data lanes (`D0N+D0P`...`D3N+D3P`).

What kind of adapter will I need to connect it to Raspberry Pi 4's MIPI-DSI [which is 2-lane 15-pin MIPI](https://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_LCD/Raspberry_Pi_LCD_DSI_Display_Connector.html)?

I would be also happy to connect to HDMI, but again, what is the right driver board for that?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in data lanes comes from the resolution requirements: The LCD panel you plan to use has a four-lane (diff pair) input because its resolution is 2560x1400. The RPi has a two-lane output because it's capable of displaying lower resolutions. Therefore, you may not be able to use that LCD panel with your RPi.

> I would be also happy to connect to HDMI, but again, what is the right driver board for that?

This is completely a different story. Since product recommendations are off-topic here, I can't say anything about your request.